# Get time difference between two values in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing, time

I trying to get the avarage, max and min time difference between value occurrences in a csv file.
The contains a multiple columns and rows. 
I am currently working in python and trying to use pandas to solve my problem.

I have managed to break down the csv file to the column i want to get the time difference from and the time column.
Where the "payload" column "value occurrences" happens.
looking like:

time | payload
12.1   2368
13.8   2508

I have also tried to get the time in a array when the value occurrences happens and tried to step through the array but failed bad. I felt like there was a easier way to do it.

```py
def average_time(avg_file):
    avg_read = pd.read_csv(avg_file, skiprows=2, names=new_col_names, usecols=[2, 3], na_filter=False, skip_blank_lines=True)
    test=[]
    i=0
    for row in avg_read.payload:
        if row != None:
            test[i]=avg_read.time
            i+=1
            if len[test] > 2:
                average=test[1]-test[0]
                i=0
                test=[]
    return average
```

The csv-file currently look like:

```
time    |   payload
12.1        2250
12.5        2305
12.9        (blank)
13.1        (blank)
13.5        2309
14.6        2350
14.9        2680
15.0        (blank)
```

I want to get the time diffenrence between the values in the payload columen. example time between

```
2250 and 2305 --> 12.5-12.1 = 0.4 sec
```

and the get the difference between

```
2305 and 2309 --> 13.5-12.5 = 1 s
```

Skipping the blank numbers
To later on get the maximum, minimun and average difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `dropna` then use `Series.diff`

DataFrame used:

```
print(df)
   time  payload
0  12.1   2250.0
1  12.5   2305.0
2  12.9      NaN
3  13.1      NaN
4  13.5   2309.0
5  14.6   2350.0
6  14.9   2680.0
7  15.0      NaN
```

---

```
df.dropna().time.diff()

0    NaN
1    0.4
4    1.0
5    1.1
6    0.3
Name: time, dtype: float64
```

**Note** I assumed your `(blank)` values are `NaN`, else use the following before running my code:

```
df.replace('(blank)', np.NaN, inplace=True, axis=1)

# Or if they are whitespaces

df.replace('', np.NaN, inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Comment: Ah works great! Thank you alot:)

Comment: Dont forget to accept as answer if it helped you :) @snaz